# Silex security doesn't ask name and password

Tags: apache, security, silex

I am using Silex and apache. I want to disallow access for anonymous users to localhost/admin page. I read [docs](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html), [docs of SimpleUserProvider](http://www.jasongrimes.org/2014/09/simple-user-management-in-silex/) and create the following index.php:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
use Silex\Provider;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
$app = new Silex\Application();
$app->register(new Provider\SecurityServiceProvider());
$app->register(new Provider\SessionServiceProvider());
$app->register(new Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), [
    "twig.path" => __DIR__.'/../views'
]);
$app['debug'] = true;
$app['security.firewalls'] = array(
    'default' => array(
        'pattern' => '^/',
    ),
    'secured' => array(
        'pattern' => '^/admin/',
        'form' => array('login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/login_check'),
        'users' => array(
            'admin' => array('ROLE_ADMIN', '5FZ2Z8QIkA7UTZ4BYkoC+GsReLf569mSKDsfods6LYQ8t+a8EW9oaircfMpmaLbPBh4FOBiiFyLfuZmTSUwzZg=='),
        'daria' => array('ROLE_USER', '5FZ2Z8QIkA7UTZ4BYkoC+GsReLf569mSKDsfods6LYQ8t+a8EW9oaircfMpmaLbPBh4FOBiiFyLfuZmTSUwzZg=='),
        ),
    ),
);
$app['security.access_rules'] = array(
    array('^/admin', 'ROLE_ADMIN', 'https'),
    array('^.*$', 'ROLE_USER'),
);
$app -> boot();
$app->get('/', function () {
    return 'Hello from Silex container.';
});
$app->get('/admin/', function() {
    return "Admin page";
});
$app->get('/login', function(Request $request) use ($app) {
    return "Login page";
});
$app->get('/logout/', function() {
    return "Logout page";
});
$app->get('/admin/login_check/', function() {
    return "Admin login check page";
});
$app->run();
```

As  [Symfony 2 docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/book/security.html) says, if I request to localhost/admin, I should see input fields for pass and login in alert. 
So when I go to 'localhost' all are right, I see correct message. But when I go to 'localhost/admin' I expect that browser will ask with alert my login and password. But it doesn't happens, I get 'ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED Site localhost disallow connection'. In apache log I have 301 http code. Is it normal behavior that browser doesn't ask login/password with alert? If yes, what should I add to code to change that behavior?

P.S. I know that hardcoded login and password are terrible, but I am just started Silex and it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I think that you get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error because of redirect to https. Try to remove this redirect by changing `array('^/admin', 'ROLE_ADMIN', 'https'),` to `array('^/admin', 'ROLE_ADMIN'),`.
2. Remove `default` section from firewalls. This section is first, catches all requests and doesn't require authorization.
3. If you want standard alert with user/password prompt, specify `http` entry point instead of `form`.

---

```
$app['security.firewalls'] = array(
    'secured' => array(
        'pattern' => '^/admin/',
        'http' => array(),
        'users' => array(
            'admin' => array('ROLE_ADMIN', '...'),
            'daria' => array('ROLE_USER', '...'),
        ),
    ),
);
```